# How to stop SVG color from changing after clicking on an area?

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg map and I don't want the color to change after clicking on an area. as seen in pic. it looks like a hyperlink after visiting.

```
.mapdiv {
max-width: 45%;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: auto;
stroke: #a9a9a9!important;
stroke-width: 2px;
stroke-linejoin: round;
fill: #5d6675;!important;}

.mapdiv path {
opacity: .85;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 150ms;
-moz-transition: all 150ms;
-o-transition: all 150ms;
transition: all 150ms; }

.mapdiv :hover {
stroke-width: 3px;
stroke-linejoin: round;
fill: #c9b394!important;
cursor: pointer; }
```

[my svg map after clicking on some areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0z49.png)

Comment: Use a javascript event listener to change the fill instead of css hover

Comment: I did try with JS and no luck =(

Comment: "I did try ..." - please provide the try

Comment: I used JQuery here is what I used <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("path").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("fill", "#c9b394");
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("fill", "#5d6675");
  });
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

ok bad habits are bad for a reason, after removing all !important from my CSS it got fixed, not sure why or how but it got fixed.